# how do I return list with separate character

Tags: python

I have a string s = '10001001'.
When I use:

```
return [s[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(s), 4)]
```

it returns

```
['1000','1001']
```

How can I modify my code to get

```
[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: @jdaz you also have to convert each character to an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
s = '10001001'
r = [list(map(int, s[i:i+4])) for i in range(0, len(s), 4)]
print(r) # [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from @jdaz suggestion, a list comprehension within a list comprehension is one way:

```
[[int(v) for v in s[i:i+4]] for i in range(0, len(s), 4)]
```

The range iterator splits it in chunks of 4 characters. The inner list comprehension loops over each character and passes that as a list.

What you will get is lists within a list:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```